# Importing Image MVVM WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm new to WPF and while I'm trying to learn it I came across MVVM framework. Now I'm trying to implement it with a simple application i made which imports and displays an image.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="mvvmSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="1024" Height="768">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Imported Picture">
        <Image x:Name="_image" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <Button Height="50" Grid.Row="1" Content="Import Picture"    Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace mvvmSample
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.DefaultExt = (".png");
        open.Filter = "Pictures (*.jpg;*.gif;*.png)|*.jpg;*.gif;*.png";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
            _image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(open.FileName));
      }
   }
}
```

I watched alot of tutorial on mvvm for beginners and read alot of articles about it and i grasp the concept behind it. With my application I'm assuming the view would be the same as what i have but without using events but rather using command binding for both source and button. For model, I would assume I should have an image property but I'm not sure if it should get and set the filepath or the image itself. The View Model would then contain functions for both image retrieval (OpenFileDialog) and command for the button. Are my assumptions correct or is there a better way of transforming this application into mvvm. A sample coding would be great so I can analyze it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Go try Caliburn.Micro; ViewModels as a resource of the View is a horrible pattern. I'd recommend you implement the Dependency injection with either NInject or Autofac, or alike. Trust me you will enjoy MVVM a lot more if you pick a decent framework like Caliburn.Micro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ViewModel you should define the logic you want to execute when you click the button. To do that, you need to use a command. My suggestion is use a [`RelayCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx), which is a generic command:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    //[DebuggerStepThrough]
    /// <summary>
    /// Defines if the current command can be executed or not
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="parameter"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Assuming that you are using the `RelayCommand` as defined above you need to supply it with one or two delegates, one that returns a bool which determines whether the command is in a valid state to be run, and a second which returns nothing and actually runs the command. If you don't supply a `CanExecute` delegate then the command will consider that it is always in a valid state.

In your ViewModel, you also need a property to save te Image path. This property will be bind with the `Source` property of the `Image` that you have in the View. So, your ViewModel class would be like this:

```
public class MainViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string imagePath;

    public string ImagePath
    {
        get { return imagePath; }
        set
        {
            imagePath = value;
            SetPropertyChanged("ImagePath");
        }
    }

    ICommand _loadImageCommand;
    public ICommand LoadImageCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_loadImageCommand == null)
            {
                _loadImageCommand = new RelayCommand(param => LoadImage());
            }
            return _loadImageCommand;
        }
    }

    private void LoadImage()
    {
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.DefaultExt = (".png");
        open.Filter = "Pictures (*.jpg;*.gif;*.png)|*.jpg;*.gif;*.png";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
            ImagePath = open.FileName;
    }

    #region Property Changed Event Handler
    protected void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    #endregion Property Changed Event Handler
}
```

With this ViewModel you don't need to do anything in the code begin of your View. You just instantiate your ViewModel in the window's resources and set the `DataContext` property of the root grid. After that, you can bind the properties and commands with the proper controls:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="1024" Height="768">
<Window.Resources>
    <wpfApplication1:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Imported Picture">
        <Image x:Name="_image" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ImagePath}"/>
    </GroupBox>
    <Button Height="50" Grid.Row="1" Content="Import Picture" Command="{Binding LoadImageCommand}"  />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So I'm guessing the generic class relaycommand I can use if I implement other buttons like zoom and save, but for the ICommand is it possible to make it generic aswell? Also, I think I would need to add ViewModel Namespace in there so i can invoke(if thats the correct verbage to use) it as a window resources because i tried using it as you have it and wpfApplication1 only shows APP and no MainViewMOdel.

Comment: Yes, you can use the RelayCommand when you need to define one of those events you mention. The namespace that I show in my answer, is the namespace where I define the ViewModel in my app, so, you need to change it by yours.

Answer (score 0):

To Octavioccl

I did use my own namespace in my coding as so:

```
<Window x:Class="mvvmSample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mvvmSample="clr-namespace:mvvmSample"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:mvvmSample.ViewModel"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="1024" Height="768">
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{StaticResource MainViewModel}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GroupBox Grid.Row="0" Header="Imported Picture">
        <Image x:Name="_image" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />
    </GroupBox>
    <Button Height="50" Grid.Row="1" Content="Import Picture" Command="{Binding LoadedImageCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I have both:

```
xmlns:mvvmSample="clr-namespace:mvvmSample"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:mvvmSample.ViewModel"
```

I added the later since I cannot access the MainViewModel in Window.Resources without it and mvvmSample only have App as choice. The program runs but it doesn't do anything it just shows the UI and if i click the button nothing happens. I placed breakpoints in several places like in RelayCommand and MainWindow code behind to be able to observe the problem, but it just initialize components and shows the UI.

Update:

I was able to solve this problem which was totally my fault. I wrote the wrong function name in binding instead of LoadImage I have LoadedImage thats why my button click doesnt activate "DUH". Thanks for all your help.